# How to make two threads work in same time

Tags: java, multithreading

I make two threads: one for fill an array and the second one print it. It seems like the two thread don't  work in same time.

When i run the code its print first thread working then its print the array and second thread working how i can know if they working on same time or not?

here is my code:

```
public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        firstthread f=new firstthread();            
        secondthread s=new secondthread();

        s.start();
        f.start();         
    }

}
```

and the class the contain both fill and print method:

```
public class Array {
private static int [] ar=new int[500];

 public static void fillarray()
 {
     for (int i = 0; i < ar.length; i++)         
            ar[i]=i;
 }

 public static void printarray()
 {
     for (int i = 0; i < ar.length; i++)         
          System.out.print(ar[i]+" ");  
 }
 }
```

the first thread class:

```
    public class firstthread extends Thread{

            public void  run() {

                   Array.fillarray();
                System.out.print("first thread working ");

            }

    }
```

the second thread class:

```
    public class secondthread extends Thread{


        public void run() {

            Array.printarray();

            System.out.println("second array working");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Nothing about computer is completely synchronized, just saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want an implementation of producer-consumer problem bro... Frankly speaking, without having a lock on the Object's monitor, you dont have control over anything. You dont have control over how much time a thread executes (Timeslice provided to it). If the time slice is too long, you will feel that one thread executes after another because your processor is so fast, your first thread will get ample time to finish its work . If you want to know how threads work exactly, use wait() and notify() and synchronized methods to change it into a producer-consumer problem.

1. Jeanne is also right, you can put sleep() , there's a 90 percent chance that it might work.
2. You could increase the number of elements being filled/printed.
3. There's a 70% chance of you reading more than what you wrote(filled in the array) if you dont use syncronized/wait/notify.

Comment: ok thx now i get what i should do but i was want them to work in turn like one time firstthread is faster than second soo the printed value gonna be number then the second thread to be faster soo the printed value gonna be zeros and so on

Comment: sorry.. But i am not getting what you want exactly.

Answer (score 2):

The fillarray and printarray methods are running too fast so you aren't getting threading.

Add Thread.sleep(10) to each loop.  That way the code will run much slower and the threads will intersperse.  They will probably alternate with this approach.

Then change in to sleep a random # of seconds and you'll see different behavior.

Comment: i made the array index too big i get some thing but i think i should get list of 0 0 0 0 instead of 1 2 3 etc cuz maybe printarray method start before fill array and when i sleep first thread i got a list of 0 0 0 0

Comment: i need them to start fill some piece of array and print then print 0 0 0 cuz there is a delay in fillarray i want it to be like this 0123 0007801011

Comment: With this method, you are running a risk of reading more than what you wrote (filled)

Answer (score 1):

Starting a thread takes some time to the JVM. The first thread executes its run() method faster than the other thread is started. That's why you see that behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Question isn't clear. Do you mean how can you tell if they are working on the same array? If that is the case the answer is Yes. the array is static meaning there would be only one of its kind which would belong to the class array. So there wont be multiple instances of it being worked on by the different threads.

As stated above, the threads run very fast. So even though they are accessing the same object, one thread would finish its job before the second even begins

Comment: what i need that to see the behavior of multithreading and what happen here its like what u say 1 finish then the second begins how i can make more useful to understand this idea ?